# Can a GMM clustering contain an empty cluster?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Suppose we want to train a 1-dimension GMM clustering algorithm on 2 points: 0,2, using 2 clusters.
Suppose the initialization is:
Gaussian 1: mean 1, variance 1. 
Gaussian 2: mean 5, variance 1.

After running the algorithm, what gaussian clusters will we get? Will the second gaussian be empty while the first contains the 2 points?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible even when the number of data points exceeds the number of components. Your example will not produce an empty cluster. Instead, it will converge with

```
Gaussian 1: mean=0.000000, variance=0.000001, weights=0.500000
Gaussian 2: mean=2.000000, variance=0.000001, weights=0.500000
```

I posted the code to generate this below. The GMM's density function looks like this:

[image]

The reason for why the second Gaussian is used by the GMM is that it is always beneficial for the model to pull the Gaussian closer to 2. This will increase the likelihood of the second data point while not decreasing the likelihood of any other data points. You can think of the Gaussian means as being attached to the data points by springs.

### Example with empty cluster

Here is an example, where one Gaussian results in an empty cluster / is not used by the GMM.

```
Data: [-0.1, 0.1, 9.9, 10.1]
Components: 3
Initial Weights: [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]
Initial Means: [0, 5, 10]
Initial Variances: [1, 1, 1]
```

That results in the following GMM:

```
Gaussian 1: mean=-0.000000, variance=0.010001, weights=0.500000
Gaussian 2: mean=5.000000, variance=24.989993, weights=0.000000
Gaussian 3: mean=10.000000, variance=0.010001, weights=0.500000
```

[image]

### Code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

X = np.array([-0.1, 0.1, 9.9, 10.1])
X = X.reshape((len(X), 1))
plot_xs = np.linspace(-1, 11, 1000)

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=3, weights_init=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3], 
                      means_init=[[0], [5], [10]],
                      precisions_init=[[[1]], [[1]], [[1]]])
gmm.fit(X)

for i in range(3):
    print('Gaussian %d: mean=%f, variance=%f, weights=%f' 
          % (i+1, gmm.means_[i], gmm.covariances_[i], gmm.weights_[i]))

# Plot
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(plot_xs, gmm.weights_[i] * 
             norm.pdf(plot_xs, gmm.means_[i][0], np.sqrt(gmm.covariances_[i][0][0])))
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you please tell, how to find maximum likelihood for each iteration for GMM